# How to handle press state from inside the button if contentItem is defined from the outside?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom button that shows a white overlay over the content and background area when pressed. The user of the button can specify how to align the content (label + text) by defining the contentItem.

The current implementation works, but I would like to control the press state inside the button. How can the button display the white overlay on top of the contentItem from within the button?

I prefer not to add a bunch of properties to the button to define the layout of the text/icon. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Working code so far:

```
 ButtonOverlay {
    id: btnOverlay
    width: 100
    height: 50
    state: ""
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        Label {
            text: "button"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rectId
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "white"
            opacity: 0.5
            visible: btnOverlay.state === "pressed"
        }
    }
    onPressed: {
          btnOverlay.state = "pressed"
    }
    onReleased: {
          btnOverlay.state = ""
    }
}
```

ButtonOverlay.qml

```
Button {
   id: root

   background: Rectangle {
      radius: 10
      color: "gray"

      Rectangle {
        id: overlay
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: parent.radius
        visible: root.state === "pressed"
        color: "white"
        opacity: 0.5
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Should the user only be able to position and layout the `contentItem` (Text)? Do you actually want to have the overlay in the `Button`? If yes the overlay and its behavior should be defined from the outside as is. Instead of `state` you can just bind to the buttons `pressed` property.

Comment: I would like to help, but don't understand the question. Could you clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes, the user should only be able to position and layout the contentItem and the overlay should be inside the ButtonOverlay.qml so the user doesn't have to handle it. Right now I have 2 overlays: one for background and one for contentItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the overlay in the `contentItem` and moved the overlay from the `background` into the `Button`. Furthermore I've used the `z` property to change the drawing order.

```
component ButtonOverlay: Button {
    id: btn

    background: Rectangle {
        radius: 10
        color: "gray"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: overlay
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: btn.background.radius
        color: "white"
        opacity: 0.5
        visible: btn.pressed
        z: 1
    }
}

ButtonOverlay {
    width: 100
    height: 50
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        color: "red"

        Label { text: "button" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `Frame` for your `ButtonOverlay`. `Frame` works by automatically sizing to your inner contents but allows you to easily replace the borders via the `background` property. To use it, you will have to move the entire `Button` out:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ButtonOverlay {
        id: btnOverlay
        pressed: btn.pressed
        Button {
            id: btn
            width: 100
            height: 50
            implicitWidth: width
            implicitHeight: height
            contentItem: Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                Label {
                    text: "button"
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: rectId
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "white"
                    opacity: 0.5
                    visible: btnOverlay.pressed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ButtonOverlay.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Frame {
    id: root
    
    property bool pressed: false
    
    background: Rectangle {
        radius: 10
        color: "gray"
        
        Rectangle {
            id: overlay
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: parent.radius
            visible: pressed
            color: "white"
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAERHichVPBboMwDL3nK6J+AO0OvXDcpGmVJnXdZecALkQNhDmmHZr67wukQFPSzgeE7Wfj52dkWWskvqNdI9MDk54bveiKUCvDPkQO/Jdxa88Nka62R0Al2kusM5nFPKEhMYZrBGPA5aKLMyZdr6smV4282ElmVMT8abXywgXIvKCYr/2wZaFkKunLVfXFQcDbpd718SCppQ4VbQjKmH9CSqLKFdyM6oBKY8wXCNlilnwXCahAUWcEP/bTi6Tfwbz0PIs8mqJnZReHFrPJgmlRpYVGE+2lUjGvBVp6QeDA6FRIgvlgnela2PW1MV9F6yDgKI1MFFyfxEz9MNPJc29ndmZsufTvLvouFbu51rvHy15RlMPS+iVp7Zj3jxp1DUgtT7RW073uhTIwoRKRHnLUTZWFzwFFJhvTnegYGvaYo2inNY4v9+TsJtQ3f1Fn/+o3jOBSkXM9xKhKSIoHsgflHuX5A2ThFHM=)